# Sub in R pattern

Tags: r

I am trying to work out how the Sub works in R. I was trying to break a list up into two sections. For instance, i have this working for list_2, where Var1 = 0_300 and var2 = minus 5.

```
    list_2 <- c("area_0_300_minus5",     
                "area_0_300_minus4" ,    
                "area_0_300_minus3"  ,   
                "area_0_300_minus2"   ,  
                "area_0_300_minus1"    , 
                "area_0_300_0"          ,
                "area_0_300_1"          ,
                "area_0_300_2"          ,
                "area_0_300_3"         ,
                "area_0_300_4"          ,
                "area_0_300_5"          ,
                "area_300_600_minus5"   ,
                "area_300_600_minus4"   ,
                "area_300_600_minus3"   ,
                "area_300_600_minus2"   ,
                "area_300_600_minus1"   ,
                "area_300_600_0"        ,
                "area_300_600_1"       ,
                "area_300_600_2"        ,
                "area_300_600_3"        ,
                "area_300_600_4"        ,
                "area_300_600_5"        ,
                "area_600_800_minus5"   ,
                "area_600_800_minus4"   ,
                "area_600_800_minus3"   ,
                "area_600_800_minus2"   ,
                "area_600_800_minus1"  ,
                "area_600_800_0"        ,
                "area_600_800_1"        ,
                "area_600_800_2"        ,
                "area_600_800_3"        ,
                "area_600_800_4"        ,
                "area_600_800_5"       )

    var1_working = sub("^.*_(\\d+_\\d+)_.*$", "\\1", list_2)
    var2_working = sub("^.*_(.*)$", "\\1", list_2)
```

But in my list 1, i cant seem to extract 0_300 etc to equal to var1 and the 'm5'/ 'm4' / 'm3' / 'm2'  / 'm1' / '0'  / '1'  etc etc  to equal to Var2.

```
list_1 <- c("as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)0:units",   
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)0:units"  ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)0:units"  ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)0:units" ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)1:units"     ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)1:units"  ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)1:units"   ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)1:units" ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)2:units"     ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)2:units"  ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)2:units", 
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)2:units",
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)3:units",     
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)3:units",
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)3:units",   
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)3:units" ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)4:units",     
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)4:units",  
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)4:units" ,  
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)4:units",
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)5:units",     
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)5:units",  
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)5:units",   
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)5:units", 
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)m1:units",    
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)m1:units", 
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)m1:units",  
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)m1:units",
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)m2:units",    
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)m2:units",
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)m2:units" , 
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)m2:units",
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)m3:units",    
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)m3:units" ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)m3:units" , 
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)m3:units",
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)m4:units"    ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)m4:units" ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)m4:units"  ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)m4:units",
    "as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)m5:units"    ,
    "as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)m5:units",
    "as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)m5:units" , 
    "as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)m5:units")
    
    
    
    

    
    var1_nonworking = sub("^.*_(\\d+_\\d+)_.*$", "\\1", list_1)
    var2_nonworking = sub("^.*_(.*)$", "\\1", list_1)
```

I am actually just a bit unsure on how the pattern extraction works `"^.*_(\\d+_\\d+)_.*$", "\\1"` which means quite little to me to be able to adapt it to my list 1.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. `strcapture` returns a frame, one column per capture group.

   ```r
   strcapture(".*\\)([^:]*).*\\)([^:]*):.*", list_1,
              proto = list(var1 = "", var2 = ""))[c(1:3, 42:44),]
   #        var1 var2
   # 1     0_300    0
   # 2   300_600    0
   # 3   600_800    0
   # 42  300_600   m5
   # 43  600_800   m5
   # 44 800_1000   m5
   ```
2. `gregexpr` to extract zero or more per line of text.

   ```r
   gre <- gregexpr("(?<=\\))([^:]*)(?=:)", list_1, perl = TRUE)
   regmatches(list_1, gre)[c(1:3, 42:44)]
   # [[1]]
   # [1] "0_300" "0"    
   # [[2]]
   # [1] "300_600" "0"      
   # [[3]]
   # [1] "600_800" "0"      
   # [[4]]
   # [1] "300_600" "m5"     
   # [[5]]
   # [1] "600_800" "m5"     
   # [[6]]
   # [1] "800_1000" "m5"
   ```

Comment: Hi r2evans, but in this example it only gets a list of 6 elements when it should be around 20/30? For instance, 0_300 in var1 will be repeated x10 according to var2 with m5,m4,m3,m2,m1,0,1,2,3,4,5 and then the same pattern for 300_600. The m5, m4 variables for each list element is just before ':units'

Comment: sorry - i probably didnt explain the question very well

Comment: Remove my indexing `[c(1:3,42:44)]`, I did that because I didn't want to show all 44 on the screen here. The method works, I chose to not show it all, that's all.

Comment: @TomBenson did that fix your issue?

Comment: worked to perfection! thank you. I think my issue was not really understanding how expressions worked .. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2):

Using the input shown in the Note at the end to avoid excessive length replace the last underscore with a space and then read that using `read.table`.

Regarding the regular expression the dot matches any character and the star means as many characters as possible, i.e. it is greedy, or zero characters if not possible. The underscore matches itself.  The replacement argument in `sub` refers to the first and only capture group which is the part of the string that matches the parenthesized part of the regular expression.

With this approach only relatively simple regular expressions are needed.

```
read.table(text = sub("(.*)_", "\\1 ", list_2))
##           V1     V2
## 1 area_0_300 minus5
## 2 area_0_300 minus4
## 3 area_0_300 minus3
## 4 area_0_300 minus2
## 5 area_0_300 minus1
## 6 area_0_300      0
```

Similarly for list_1 replace all occurrences of : and ) with a space, read it in and extract columns 2 and 4.

```
read.table(text = gsub("[:)]", " ", list_1))[c(2, 4)]
##         V2 V4
## 1    0_300  0
## 2  300_600  0
## 3  600_800  0
## 4 800_1000  0
## 5    0_300  1
## 6  300_600  1
```

### Note

```
list_2 <- c("area_0_300_minus5",     
                "area_0_300_minus4",    
                "area_0_300_minus3",   
                "area_0_300_minus2",  
                "area_0_300_minus1", 
                "area_0_300_0")

list_1 <- c("as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)0:units",   
"as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)0:units",
"as.factor(radius_ring)600_800:as.factor(year_delta)0:units",
"as.factor(radius_ring)800_1000:as.factor(year_delta)0:units",
"as.factor(radius_ring)0_300:as.factor(year_delta)1:units",
"as.factor(radius_ring)300_600:as.factor(year_delta)1:units")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions are not that far from working status:

As to the first, you need to assert that there must not be any digits preceding the digit string you want to match. This assertion is implemented by the negative character class `\\D` (with upper-case D), which matches any character that is *not* a digit:

```
sub("^\\D+(\\d+_\\d+).*$", "\\1", list_1)
 [1] "0_300"    "300_600"  "600_800"  "800_1000" "0_300"    "300_600"  "600_800"  "800_1000" "0_300"    "300_600"  "600_800"  "800_1000" "0_300"   
[14] "300_600"  "600_800"  "800_1000" "0_300"    "300_600"  "600_800"  "800_1000" "0_300"    "300_600"  "600_800"  "800_1000" "0_300"    "300_600" 
[27] "600_800"  "800_1000" "0_300"    "300_600"  "600_800"  "800_1000" "0_300"    "300_600"  "600_800"  "800_1000" "0_300"    "300_600"  "600_800" 
[40] "800_1000" "0_300"    "300_600"  "600_800"  "800_1000"
```

As to the second, here things are a little more complex and `sub`is probably not the best route to take. I'd recommend `str_extract` - it does exactly the same as the (bulky) combination of `gregexpr`and `regmatches`in `base R`.

Also the substring you want to match needs to be determined *contetxually*, that is, by what precedes it and what follows it - in this case `delta` followed by `)` to the left and `:` as well as `units` to the right. Such context-based (or conditional) matching is referred to as lookaround; the syntax for positive look-behind is `(?<=...)` and the syntax for positive look-ahead is `(?=...)`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(list_1, "(?<=delta\\)).*(?=:units)")
 [1] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "5"  "5"  "5"  "5"  "m1" "m1" "m1" "m1" "m2"
[30] "m2" "m2" "m2" "m3" "m3" "m3" "m3" "m4" "m4" "m4" "m4" "m5" "m5" "m5" "m5"
```